# Excel set 1 or 0 IF any value from array is between two values from treshold

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

There is a dynamic array in Excel with some values.

Values could change based on some formulas (doesn't matter which formulas).
[image: array_values]

There are tresholds (0-31, 61-85 and so on).
[image: tresholds]

Based on these tresholds if any value from the first row of the array is between 0-31 then CM-11 should be 1, else 0.

For CM-12 we should take 31-61 and check if values 25,26,185,625 in this treshold or not. So in this case now it will be 0 since the criteria is false.
And so on for every cell.

Is there any sophisticated approach to solve and automate this task applying Excel formulas? 
Or any other approach usingExcel?

[image: array_and_tresholds]

Comment: You can do with a `CountIfs()` to capture < or > thresholds.

Comment: I am confused by this sentence `For CM-12 we should take 31-61 and check if values 25,26,185,625 in this threshold or not`. I thought you would only check if values **under** CM-12 are between 31 and 61. But based on what you said you also want to compare values under CM-13 and CM-14 with 31 and 61? If that's not what you mean please correct your original post. If that's exactly what you want, please specify the rules for CM-13 and CM-14, or confirm the other numbers in the Threshold row `85`, `101` are irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

Using this formula, as displayed in the further down image, you can count items in a range that are between thresholds:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$D$4,"<"&F9,$B$2:$D$4,">"&E9)
```

Note the `"<"&` tied to a cell reference...

[image]

Checked for my small array if values were between 0 & 2, 2 & 4, 4 & 10, and 10 & 11.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem, I tried to put the images to help, you just need to adjust the correct cells

put a imput cell, a base value and a upper value to define the condition and put in the cell below

```
=uppercell + 30
```

[image]

Then use the following formula:

```
=if(and(base cell < input; imput < upper cell); 1; 0)
```

[image: image2]